# How do you call a class from a command when a button is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to delete the frame plus add a new frame in a class, using the command function in the button. How do I call a class?

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a button, you can pass a function to the 'command' argument of its constructor. When the user clicks on the button, the function will be called. You generally want to keep a reference to the object which holds the callable:

```
class O:
    def fn(self): pass
x = O()
Button(root, command=x.fn)
```

... but that is not necessary:

```
class O:
    def fn(self): pass
Button(root, command=O().fn)
```